# Prediction with CI - predict.glm doesn't have interval option

Tags: r, confidence-interval, generalized-linear-model, prediction

I have a model and a graph:

```
n1 = glm(formula = cbind(ml, ad) ~ x1, family = "quasibinomial")
plot(x1, ml/(ml+ad))
```

And I would like to plot a predicted line with a confidence interval. I would like to write this (as in predict.lm):

```
predict_n1s <- predict.glm(n1, data.frame(x1 = seq(..)), type = "response", 
                           interval = c("confidence"))
```

**But the `interval` option doesn't work for `predict.glm`! Is there any possibility how to call this?**

If there is not, is this workaround OK?

```
n1_x <- seq(par("usr")[1], par("usr")[2], length.out = 200)
predict <- predict.glm(n1, data.frame(x1 = n1_x), type = "link", se.fit = TRUE)
lines(x = n1_x, y = n1$family$linkinv(predict$fit), col = "red")
lines(x = n1_x, y = n1$family$linkinv(predict$fit + predict$se.fit * 1.96), col = "red", lty = 2)
lines(x = n1_x, y = n1$family$linkinv(predict$fit - predict$se.fit * 1.96), col = "red", lty = 2)
```

Comment: Your workaround appears to be Wald-based confidence intervals, not prediction intervals. See [mail 1](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Re-Can-not-get-a-prediction-interval-from-Predict-td885947.html) and [mail 2](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2003-May/033165.html) on the R-help list.

Comment: I think we should use the binomial distribution instead of the normal one.

Comment: There are still CIs based on the coefficients alone. For a prediction interval, you'd need to do something with a quantile function.